# Adding fields to Solr using the API

Tags: solr

I am very new to solr. I am trying to add a large number of fields to the schema. I am using version 8.1, and it is my understanding that it should be done through the API.
I am trying to upload all fields using curl, but keep getting errors. It works fine through the web interface.

1. Where can I find the correct field types?
 I checked
[here](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_1/field-types-included-with-solr.html#field-types-included-with-solr), but I get error messages like "Field type 'StrField' not found".
The values are also different from the ones that I get presented with in the webinterface.

2. Enum values
I found [documentation](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_1/working-with-enum-fields.html#defining-an-enumfieldtype-in-schema-xml), which also results in an unknown field error. For enumns I don't see an option in the web interface.
<\p>

```
 curl -X POST -H 'Content-type:application/json' --data-binary '{"add-field":{"name":"TEST","type":"string","required":"true","stored":true,"indexed":"true"}}' http://localhost:8983/api/cores/tgec/schema
```

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":400,
    "QTime":27},
  "error":{
    "metadata":[
      "error-class","org.apache.solr.api.ApiBag$ExceptionWithErrObject",
      "root-error-class","org.apache.solr.api.ApiBag$ExceptionWithErrObject"],
    "details":[{
        "add-field":{
          "name":"TEST",
          "type":"StrField",
          "required":"true",
          "stored":true,
          "indexed":"true"},
        "errorMessages":["Field 'TEST': Field type 'StrField' not found.\n"]}],
    "msg":"error processing commands",
    "code":400}}
```

Comment: There is not type called "strField", it has to be "string".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is field type named `"string"` and the class is of `"solr.StrField"`.

Its defined in `schema.xml` as below.

```
<fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" docValues="true" />
```

Then when you define a field, you mention a type string to it as below.

```
<field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
```

You need to change the `"type":"StrField"` to `"type":"string"`.

Comment: Thank you. So that means that I do need to modify the managedSchema?

Comment: As off now it looks like you don't have to modify the managed schema file. But if you are trying to create the field through the API then you need to modify the API call where you are passing type as strfield, and pass string as the type

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I am currently travelling. Yes, it did, thank you! I got now a better idea how to interact with solr. I got data back and also managed to add field types. Now stuck with that solr is not displaying everything I'd like to see, but that will be a different question.